# Logical volume missing after reboot

Tags: linux, lvm, nfs

Centos- 6, LVM2
after a system hang and hard reboot.

`lvdisplay` and `lvscan` return no volumes. It had volumes earlier...how to recover?

there is data on LV (logical volume) - shared as NFS export..

VG is listed under /etc/lvm/backup/datastore1. any ideas to restore the LV?

```
vgdisplay  
  -- Volume group --  
  VG Name               datastore1  
  System ID  
  Format                lvm2  
  Metadata Areas        1  
  Metadata Sequence No  1  
  VG Access             read/write  
  VG Status             resizable  
  MAX LV                0  
  Cur LV                0  
  Open LV               0  
  Max PV                0  
  Cur PV                1  
  Act PV                1  
  VG Size               10.92 TiB  
  PE Size               4.00 MiB  
  Total PE              2861467  
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0  
  Free  PE / Size       2861467 / 10.92 TiB  
  VG UUID               7uq001-dUxd-I1WS-PPu2-ljT3-FybY-D9ddx2
```

cat /etc/lvm/backup/datastore1

```
datastore1 {
    id = "7uq001-dUxd-I1WS-PPu2-ljT3-FybY-D9ddx2"
    seqno = 2
    status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
    flags = []
    extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
    max_lv = 0
    max_pv = 0
    metadata_copies = 0

    physical_volumes {

            pv0 {
                    id = "kRGDrz-YFyf-EIKk-0om6-9H78-jgle-9z0B27"
                    device = "/dev/cciss/c0d1p1"    # Hint only

                    status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                    flags = []
                    dev_size = 23441142637  # 10.9156 Terabytes
                    pe_start = 2048
                    pe_count = 2861467      # 10.9156 Terabytes
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: you might run `vgscan` or `vgdisplay` to see the status of the volume groups. If a volume group is inactive, you'll have the issues you've described. You'll have to run `vgchange` with the appropriate parameters to reactivate the VG. Consult your system documentation for the appropriate flags. You'll be able to run `vgscan` and then `lvscan` afterwards to bring up your LVs.

Comment: Normally LVM should preserve all settings. This is neither a NFS-problem, nor a LVM problem. Perhaps you should change the title of your question...

Comment: changed the question, thx

Comment: Anything in /etc/lvm/backup/datastore1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're about to restore the LVM partiton scheme from backup file , you could try:

`vgcfgrestore datarestore1`

If everything is ok , try activate all LVs by:

`vgchange -ay`

And do a fsck on all volums with `fsck` , e.g `fsck /dev/datarestore1/XX`

If no errors occured , try mount them by `mount -a`

Comment: does not seem to work.......after step #2: vgchange -ay ...."0 logical volumes in datastore1 active"

Comment: @maruti maybe you can share your `/etc/lvm/backup/datarestore1` ?

Comment: @maruti seems broken , I see two unmatched '{'

Comment: @warlock.....I missed some earlier ...check now...

Comment: @maruti bad news , i think it's not recoverable from backup cfg file , normally you should see a entry named "logical_volumes" , which contains info of LVs , your config seems to have PV info only ...

Comment: @ oh okay...can LV be lost so easily....system underwent a hard reboot? please let me know where i can get info on LVM survival tricks. thanks for your support....you have the points...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3624/discussion-between-warl0ck-and-maruti)

Comment: +1 fixed an issue I was having.. answer is worth millions